# Анимация gif в winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация

Есть анимация формата gif.

```
Image i = Properties.Resources.y4;
pictureBox1.Image = i;
ImageAnimator.Animate(i, OnFrameChanged);
```

1. Как я могу перемещаться по шагам, ну у меня идет анимация стрелочки вверх, вниз, вправо, влево. Могу я в зависимости от ситуации отрисовать картинку стрелочки вправо? то есть как то ходить по шагам?
2. Как по клику кнопки скрыть анимацию, так как `pictureBox1.Enabled = false`; просто ее останавливает.
3. Почему никак не работает `ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(i, OnFrameStop);`

Comment: Предположу, что проще использовать четыре отдельные картинки. Тогда в зависимости от ситуации их легко менять.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте анимацию вручную вместо использования PictureBox. Класс Image поддерживает выбор кадра анимации:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Image img;
        System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension dim;
        int frame = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
                
        private void bNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = img.GetFrameCount(dim);
            frame++;
            if (frame >= count) frame = 0;
            img.SelectActiveFrame(dim, frame);
            panel1.Invalidate();
            panel1.Update();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"...");
            Guid[] dims = img.FrameDimensionsList;

            if (dims.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error - image does not have frame dimensions!");
                return;
            }

            dim = new System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension(dims[0]);
        }        

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (img != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое