# Итерации по обеим коллекциям последовательно

Tags: c#

Был на собеседовании в одной компании и вот задали такой вопрос:

Пусть есть объект public class MultiItems, содержащий две коллекции items1 и items2. Что надо сделать с объектом, чтобы на нём можно было использовать конструкцию foreach, которая привела бы к итерации по обеим коллекциям последовательно. (yield return, yield break под капотом)

Подскажите, знает кто ответ?

Comment: Ну как что - объявить MultiItems реализующим IEnumerable. Неважно, как внутри это будет делаться, важно чтобы снаружи компилятор понимал сможет развернуть foreach. Ведь если бы вас спросили не про две коллекции, а про одну - вы бы знали ответ, верно? А тут просто вопрос на логику и понимание матчасти.

Comment: Я бы как вариант отдавал наружу кортежи через Enumerable.Zip https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @CrazyElf вы пропустили слово "последовательно" в условии задачи.

Comment: Почему среди ваших прошлых вопросов нет ни одного принятого ответа? Чтобы принять ответ, решивший ваш вопрос, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него. Например [вот один из них](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174047/373567), спасибо сказали, а ответ не приняли. Здесь лучшее спасибо - принятый ответ.

Comment: @aepot ну, последовательно можно понимать по разному, хотя скорее всего вы правы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проиллюстрирую совершенно правильный комментарий от @AK

> Ну как что - объявить MultiItems реализующим IEnumerable.

```cs
public class MultiItems<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Collection1 => ...;
    public IEnumerable<T> Collection2 => ...;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in Collection1)
            yield return item;
        foreach (T item in Collection2)
            yield return item;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumreable.GetEnumerator()
        => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Или даже через всемогущий Linq без `yield return`.

```cs
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    => Collection1.Concat(Collection2).GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: Ну и можно добавить, что foreach на самом деле требует утиную типизацию, а не явную реализацию IEnumerable